# Can MacOS Airdrop files between accounts on the same machine, logged in remotely?

Tags: macos, file-transfer, remote

I have a situation where multiple users will log in to different accounts on the same machine, and use remote screens. is it possible for one such account to airdrop to another user, who happens to be logged in to a different account on the same machine?

Comment: This would seem to be an easy task to test empirically.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, given that you'd need at least three MacOS computers available at the same time, not as easy as it is for someone who knows the answer to share their experience. Especially if you don't have three computers available. Why not stick to answering the question?